# Bicubic interpolation matlab implementation works only for grayscale images

Tags: image, matlab, image-resizing, bicubic

I am trying to implement Bicubic interpolation for image scaling in matlab. The issue is that it properly works for grayscale images, however, for colored images, the result is again in grayscale.
Please help me find out what the problem is.
Thank you.

For bicubic interpoaltion i have used the matrix containing the gradients. The matix can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation.

Here is my code.

```
input_image = im2double(imread('peppers.png'));
                x_res = 700;
                y_res = 700;

                imshow(input_image, []);


                M_inv = [
                 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
                 -3,3,0,0,-2,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
                 2,-2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3,3,0,0,-2,-1,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,-2,0,0,1,1,0,0;
                 -3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,-3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,-1,0;
                 9,-9,-9,9,6,3,-6,-3,6,-6,3,-3,4,2,2,1;
                 -6,6,6,-6,-3,-3,3,3,-4,4,-2,2,-2,-2,-1,-1;
                 2,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0;
                 0,0,0,0,2,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0;
                 -6,6,6,-6,-4,-2,4,2,-3,3,-3,3,-2,-1,-2,-1;
                 4,-4,-4,4,2,2,-2,-2,2,-2,2,-2,1,1,1,1
                 ];

                I = input_image;






                [j k c] = size(I);

                %{
                if c > 1
                    I = double(rgb2gray(I)); 
                end

                %}

                x_new = x_res;
                y_new = y_res;

                x_scale = x_new./(j-1);
                y_scale = y_new./(k-1);

                temp_image = zeros(x_new,y_new);

                Ix = double(zeros(j,k));
                for count1 = 1:j
                    for count2 = 1:k
                        if( (count2==1) || (count2==k) )
                            Ix(count1,count2)=0;
                        else
                            Ix(count1,count2)=(0.5).*(I(count1,count2+1)-I(count1,count2-1));
                        end
                    end
                end

                Iy = double(zeros(j,k));
                for count1 = 1:j
                    for count2 = 1:k
                        if( (count1==1) || (count1==j) )
                            Iy(count1,count2)=0;
                        else
                            Iy(count1,count2)=(0.5).*(I(count1+1,count2)-I(count1-1,count2));
                        end
                    end
                end

                Ixy = double(zeros(j,k));
                for count1 = 1:j
                    for count2 = 1:k
                        if( (count1==1) || (count1==j) || (count2==1) || (count2==k) )
                            Ixy(count1,count2)=0;
                        else
                            Ixy(count1,count2)=(0.25).*((I(count1+1,count2+1)+I(count1-1,count2-1)) - (I(count1+1,count2-1)+I(count1-1,count2+1)));
                        end
                    end
                end

                for count1 = 0:x_new-1
                    for count2 = 0:y_new-1

                     W = -(((count1./x_scale)-floor(count1./x_scale))-1);
                     H = -(((count2./y_scale)-floor(count2./y_scale))-1);

                     I11_index = [1+floor(count1./x_scale),1+floor(count2./y_scale)];
                     I21_index = [1+floor(count1./x_scale),1+ceil(count2./y_scale)];
                     I12_index = [1+ceil(count1./x_scale),1+floor(count2./y_scale)];
                     I22_index = [1+ceil(count1./x_scale),1+ceil(count2./y_scale)];

                     I11 = I(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
                     I21 = I(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
                     I12 = I(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
                     I22 = I(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));

                     Ix11 = Ix(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
                     Ix21 = Ix(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
                     Ix12 = Ix(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
                     Ix22 = Ix(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));

                     Iy11 = Iy(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
                     Iy21 = Iy(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
                     Iy12 = Iy(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
                     Iy22 = Iy(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));

                     Ixy11 = Ixy(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
                     Ixy21 = Ixy(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
                     Ixy12 = Ixy(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
                     Ixy22 = Ixy(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));

                     beta = [I11 I21 I12 I22 Ix11 Ix21 Ix12 Ix22 Iy11 Iy21 Iy12 Iy22 Ixy11 Ixy21 Ixy12 Ixy22];




                     alpha = M_inv*beta';
                     temp_p=0;
                     for count3 = 1:16
                        w_temp = floor((count3-1)/4);
                        h_temp = mod(count3-1,4);

                        temp_p = temp_p + alpha(count3).*((1-W)^(w_temp)).*((1-H)^(h_temp));
                     end

                    temp_image(count1+1,count2+1)=temp_p;
                    end
                end

                 output_image = temp_image;


                figure; 
                imshow(output_image);
```

Comment: That's because your code assumes it is a grayscale image.  You aren't iterating over each channel (i.e. you're not making use of the `c` variable with the output of `size`).

Comment: Could you please explain how I should be using channels and how the constant c shall be used? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your code so that it performs the interpolation on each channel individually.  Simply put, you need to make `I` each channel, create the `output_image` so that it has multiple channels and loop through each channel individually.

With these changes, we thus have:

```
input_image = im2double(imread('peppers.png'));
x_res = 700;
y_res = 700;

imshow(input_image, []);

%   input_image     -   an image on which to perform bicubic interpolation
%   x_res           -   the new horizontal dimensions (in pixels)
%   y_res           -   the new vertical dimensions (in pixels)
%Define the inverted weighting matrix, M^(-1), no need to recalculate it
%ever again


M_inv = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
         -3,3,0,0,-2,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
         2,-2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3,3,0,0,-2,-1,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,-2,0,0,1,1,0,0;
         -3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,-3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,-1,0;
         9,-9,-9,9,6,3,-6,-3,6,-6,3,-3,4,2,2,1;
         -6,6,6,-6,-3,-3,3,3,-4,4,-2,2,-2,-2,-1,-1;
         2,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0;
         0,0,0,0,2,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0;
         -6,6,6,-6,-4,-2,4,2,-3,3,-3,3,-2,-1,-2,-1;
         4,-4,-4,4,2,2,-2,-2,2,-2,2,-2,1,1,1,1
         ];

%Make a copy of the input image
%I = input_image; % Ray: Not needed here

%Determine the dimensions of the source image
%Note that we will have three values - width, height, and the number
%of color vectors, 3
[j k c] = size(input_image); % Ray: Change

%Specify the new image dimensions we want for our larger output image
x_new = x_res;
y_new = y_res;
%Determine the ratio of the old dimensions compared to the new dimensions
%Referred to as S1 and S2 in my tutorial
x_scale = x_new./(j-1);
y_scale = y_new./(k-1);

% Change by Ray - Declare new output image here with c channels
output_image = zeros(x_new, y_new, c);

% Change by Ray - Now loop through each channel
for z = 1 : c
    %Declare and initialize an output image buffer
    temp_image = zeros(x_new,y_new);

    % New - Change by Ray.  Access the right channel
    I = input_image(:,:,z);

    Ix = double(zeros(j,k));
    for count1 = 1:j
        for count2 = 1:k
            if( (count2==1) || (count2==k) )
                Ix(count1,count2)=0;
            else
                Ix(count1,count2)=(0.5).*(I(count1,count2+1)-I(count1,count2-1));
            end
        end
    end

    Iy = double(zeros(j,k));
    for count1 = 1:j
        for count2 = 1:k
            if( (count1==1) || (count1==j) )
                Iy(count1,count2)=0;
            else
                Iy(count1,count2)=(0.5).*(I(count1+1,count2)-I(count1-1,count2));
            end
        end
    end

    Ixy = double(zeros(j,k));
    for count1 = 1:j
        for count2 = 1:k
            if( (count1==1) || (count1==j) || (count2==1) || (count2==k) )
                Ixy(count1,count2)=0;
            else
                Ixy(count1,count2)=(0.25).*((I(count1+1,count2+1)+I(count1-1,count2-1)) - (I(count1+1,count2-1)+I(count1-1,count2+1)));
            end
        end
    end

    for count1 = 0:x_new-1
        for count2 = 0:y_new-1
             %Calculate the normalized distance constants, h and w
             W = -(((count1./x_scale)-floor(count1./x_scale))-1);
             H = -(((count2./y_scale)-floor(count2./y_scale))-1);
             %Determine the indexes/address of the 4 neighbouring pixels from
             %the source data/image
             I11_index = [1+floor(count1./x_scale),1+floor(count2./y_scale)];
             I21_index = [1+floor(count1./x_scale),1+ceil(count2./y_scale)];
             I12_index = [1+ceil(count1./x_scale),1+floor(count2./y_scale)];
             I22_index = [1+ceil(count1./x_scale),1+ceil(count2./y_scale)];
             %Calculate the four nearest function values
             I11 = I(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
             I21 = I(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
             I12 = I(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
             I22 = I(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));
             %Calculate the four nearest horizontal derivatives
             Ix11 = Ix(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
             Ix21 = Ix(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
             Ix12 = Ix(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));                  
             Ix22 = Ix(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));
             %Calculate the four nearest vertical derivatives
             Iy11 = Iy(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
             Iy21 = Iy(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
             Iy12 = Iy(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
             Iy22 = Iy(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));
             %Calculate the four nearest cross derivatives
             Ixy11 = Ixy(I11_index(1),I11_index(2));
             Ixy21 = Ixy(I21_index(1),I21_index(2));
             Ixy12 = Ixy(I12_index(1),I12_index(2));
             Ixy22 = Ixy(I22_index(1),I22_index(2));
             %Create our beta-vector
             beta = [I11 I21 I12 I22 Ix11 Ix21 Ix12 Ix22 Iy11 Iy21 Iy12 Iy22 Ixy11 Ixy21 Ixy12 Ixy22];

             alpha = M_inv*beta';
             temp_p=0;
             for count3 = 1:16
                 w_temp = floor((count3-1)/4);
                 h_temp = mod(count3-1,4);

                 temp_p = temp_p + alpha(count3).*((1-W)^(w_temp)).*((1-H)^(h_temp));
             end

             temp_image(count1+1,count2+1)=temp_p;
        end
    end

    % New - Change by Ray - Assign to output channel
    output_image(:,:,z) = temp_image;
end


figure; 
imshow(output_image);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, the result is in blues scale now

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I meant to use `z`. Just fixed it. Try it now. BTW, thank you for contributing your code.  We now have a canonical duplicate to refer people to if they need to implement bicubic interpolation.

Comment: Sorry, but again in grayscale with z.

Comment: @Dick No it's not. I just ran it. Please use the updates from my answer above.